# Jenkins pipeline - parallel stages merging only at the last stage

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-blueocean

I tried looking at the Jenkins pipeline documentation and more importantly the [issue JENKINS-38442](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-38442) before asking this question.

I would like to create a pipeline that looks like this: 
[image: Modified screenshot]

Basically, I would like the parallel stages to merge at different stages rather than the next stage itself. Is this possible?

The best I could do so far is only this: [image: Original Screenshot]

Below is the pipeline code that generated the above pipeline:

```
node {
   def staticTests = [:]
   staticTests["unit tests"] = {stage('unit'){ }}
   staticTests["static analysis"] = {stage('static'){ }}

   def tests = [:]
   tests["functional"] = {stage('functional'){}}
   tests["performance"] = {stage('performance'){}}
   tests["security"] = {stage('security'){}}

   stage('prepare'){}
   stage('tests'){parallel(staticTests)}
   stage('build'){}
   stage('int'){}
   stage('regression'){}
   stage('qa'){}
   stage('tests'){ parallel(tests) }
   stage('prod'){}
}
```

What changes will help me to create the pipeline as desired in the modified screenshot pasted above? Is this even possible today with Jenkins pipelines? Thank you for the help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you could write

```
node {
  stage('prepare') {}
  parallel main: {
    stage('unit tests') {}
    stage('build') {}
    stage('int') {}
    stage('regression') {}
    stage('qa') {}
    parallel functional: {}, performance: {}, security: {}
  }, 'static analysis': {}
  stage('prod') {}
}
```

which will *run* the way you request (if I understand correctly), but Blue Ocean is not currently able to display it at an appropriate level of detail, as noted in JENKINS-38442.